# Is there a way to implement a noisy CNOT gate using CUGate in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, programming, noise

Wondering if there's a way to implement the noisy version of CNOT (or CX) gate via CUGate using qiskit library for a given fidelity p?